# how to display property of method out of class

Tags: php, oop

I have created a theme class.I want to add a css file to html head by addCss method and display with displayCss method.

in my theme class I created `displayCss()` method to display the css code from `addCss()` method and I use addCss to include a css file. see head.phtml and index.php

the problem is that It doesn't display the css code in head.phtml

also another question is I call the Template class in index.php why do I have to call it again in head.phtml. If I don't call it in head.phtml I get this error

```
>  Undefined variable: theme in head.phtml
```

thanks.

```
Class Template {

    public function __construct ( $template_dir = null, $css_dir = null, $js_dir = null ) {

    if ( $template_dir !== null ) 
        $this->template_dir = $template_dir;
    if ( $css_dir !== null ) 
        $this->css_dir = $css_dir;
    if ( $js_dir !== null ) 
        $this->js_dir = $js_dir;
}

public function render ( $template_file ) {

    if ( file_exists ( $this->template_dir.$template_file ) ){
        include $this->template_dir.$template_file;
    } else {
        throw new Exception ( 'template dosyalari eksik ' . $this->template_dir . $template_file  ); 
    }
}

public function displayCss () {
    echo $this->CSS;
}

public function htmlHead () {
    self::render('head.phtml');
}

public function addCss( $css_file )
{
    if ( preg_match('/http/i', $css_file ) ) {
        $this->CSS = sprintf( '<link rel="stylesheet" href="%s">', $css_file );
    }else{

        if ( file_exists ( $this->css_dir.$css_file )  ) {
            $this->CSS = sprintf( '<link rel="stylesheet" href="%s">', $this->css_dir . $css_file );
        } else {
            $this->CSS = "css dosyasina ulasilamiyor";
        }
    }
    return $this->CSS;
}

}
```

head.phtml

```
<?php $theme = new Template(); ?>
<html>
<title>Page</title>

<?php $theme->displayCss(); ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

 require_once 'template.class.php';
 $theme = new Template();

 $theme->addCss('style.css');

 $theme->htmlHead();
```

Comment: why would you gives a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Only a clarification about classes and objects distinction. With self::something we call static function within the class definition.
When we call object functions or properties, from inside the class definition, we use the $this keyword. So function htmlHead() must be:

```
public function htmlHead () {
    $this->render('head.phtml');
}
```

According to the above, head.phtml must be:

```
<html>
<title>Page</title>

<?php $this->displayCss(); ?>
```

Because you include head.phtml in the class definition, when you call
$theme->htmlHead();
And you don't need to create a new Template object.